# Listing rights/roles on MS SQL Server 2005 and Analysis Services using Perl (or PHP)

Tags: php, sql-server, perl, security, ssas

As part of a project to create a tool to query all sorts of permissions relevant to users in our area at work, I need to query some information about our database servers.  The servers run SQL Server 2005 (including instances of Analysis Services 2005).
I need to be able to find for a given server:

- The list of logins on that server
- The list of roles on that server
- What each role has rights to
- Who is in each role (or for each login, what roles does it belong to - either way works)

The application is currently written in Perl, so if you know of techniques to use to query this information using Perl, I would be very thankful.
The only other application language I can work with is PHP, but that is to be avoided for consistency reasons if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much knowledge about SSAS, so I will leave that part of the question to someone with the appropriate experience.

For 1, 2, and 4, you should be able to use the [system stored procs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182795.aspx) sp_helplogins, sp_helprole, and sp_helprolemember.  You can also get role membership from the view sys.database_role_members.  As far as what users/roles have access to, the view sys.database_permissions contains that data.  No perl-specific methods are necessary, just your normal select and exec statements.

It might be worth a few minutes to read through the Books Online entries on system views, system tables, and system stored procs, which will return the data you want in various forms.